# Adding space before the memory block rather than after it using realloc in C

Tags: c, realloc

I have allocated an array of chars and I want to add another char at the beginning of the array while maintaining the order.

Ex. If pointer points to the beginning of 4 char blocks: **A,B,C,D -> pointer[0]==A** . If I add E the block of memory should look: **E,A,B,C,D -> pointer[0]==E**.

Additionally I want to do it in one line, without manually copying elements to another block and erasing the first. All functions have to be from C standard library.

I have though of something like **pointer = realloc(pointer-1, (n-1)*size)**, but I'm not guaranteed that pointer-1 is free.

Thankful for your answers in advance

Comment: How is the original char  array defined? How is it allocated? Is it NULL terminated? Share some code, please!

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this unless you write your own memory allocation functions.

Comment: I know of no library that allows this.  You could cheat by writing your own malloc/realloc/free library that 'cheats' by allocating some X bytes more than requested and returns a pointer to the base+X.  Bit of a bodge:(

Comment: Depending on your problem, it may be much easier if you reverse the order you are storing the character blocks in. (I realize there may be specific reasons why this is not possible). Also note that calling realloc for each character/block is going to be slow.

Comment: You *are* guaranteed that `pointer-1` is *not* a value that was previously returned by an allocation function, which is the requirement for the pointer passed to `realloc`: "If `ptr` does not match a pointer returned earlier by `calloc()`, `malloc()`, or `realloc()`… the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @RobertoCaboni , In each char insertion new, bigger memory block is reallocated, I am aware of its inefficiency but it is a part of the assignment propositions. The problem I am solving is not the one I posted, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I see, but without a _specific_ code it is not easy to provide a specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding space before the memory block rather than after it using realloc

Re-allocate with `realloc()` and then shift the data with `memove()`.

> I want to do it in one line,

Either use a helper function like below or employ a long hard to read un-maintainable line.

```
char *realloc_one_more_in_front(char *ptr, size_t current_size) {
  void *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof *ptr * (current_size + 1));
  if (new_ptr == NULL) {
    return NULL; // Failure to re-allocate.
  }
  ptr = new_ptr;
  memmove(ptr + 1, ptr, sizeof *ptr * current_size);
  return ptr;
}
```

Sample usage.  For simplicity of example, error handling omitted.

```
size_t current_size = 4;
char *ptr = malloc(current_size);
for (size_t i = 0 ; i<current_size; i++) {
  ptr[i] = 'A' + i;
}

ptr = realloc_one_more_in_front(ptr, current_size++);
ptr[0] = 'E';

printf("%.*s\n", (int) current_size, ptr);
```